# ElasticSearch credentials in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm trying to integrate Spring boot elasticsearch with a standalone ES remote server, so I've installed ES locally and it works fine.

My problem now when enable `xpack.security.enabled: true` in elasticsearch.yml file (For production purposes), I don't know how to add username & password properly.
I've tried multiple ways but useless.

my pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

my application.properties file

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=elasticsearch
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
```

it's working fine if the ES server doesn't require any authentication

Comment: Which user's credentials do you want to add in your properties file? A built-in user or one you've created?

Comment: my ES server has a username and password, I need to know how to add them in spring to be able to use  ES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming you are creating your elasticSearchOperation soemthing like this:

```
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate(final JestClient jestClient,
                                                         final ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter,
                                                         final SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext simpleElasticsearchMappingContext,
                                                         EntityMapper mapper) {
        return new JestElasticsearchTemplate(
            jestClient,
            elasticsearchConverter,
            new DefaultJestResultsMapper(simpleElasticsearchMappingContext, mapper));
    }
```

you need to configure the credentials in the JestClient which you can do like this :

```
JestHttpClient build() {
  JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
  Builder builder =
      new HttpClientConfig.Builder(cfg.urls)
          .multiThreaded(true)
          .discoveryEnabled(false)
          .connTimeout((int) cfg.connectionTimeout)
          .maxConnectionIdleTime(cfg.maxConnectionIdleTime, cfg.maxConnectionIdleUnit)
          .maxTotalConnection(cfg.maxTotalConnection)
          .readTimeout(cfg.readTimeout)
          .requestCompressionEnabled(cfg.requestCompression)
          .discoveryFrequency(1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

  if (cfg.username != null && cfg.password != null) {
    builder.defaultCredentials(cfg.username, cfg.password);
  }

  factory.setHttpClientConfig(builder.build());
  return (JestHttpClient) factory.getObject();
}
```

Note that since your server is remote you want to create the HttpClientConfig..

EDITS : Try something like this.... havent tested myself, meaning is not working/tested code but you can get an idea

```
package com.asimplemodule.config;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
    import com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.JestElasticsearchTemplate;
    import com.github.vanroy.springdata.jest.mapper.DefaultJestResultsMapper;
    import io.searchbox.client.JestClient;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchProperties;
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.EntityMapper;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ElasticsearchConverter;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext;

    import java.io.IOException;

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(ElasticsearchProperties.class)
    public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

        private ObjectMapper mapper;

        public ElasticsearchConfiguration(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        @Bean
        public EntityMapper getEntityMapper() {
            return new CustomEntityMapper(mapper);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate(                                                      final ElasticsearchConverter elasticsearchConverter,
                                                             final SimpleElasticsearchMappingContext simpleElasticsearchMappingContext,
                                                             EntityMapper mapper) {
final JestClient jestClient = createJestClient();
            return new JestElasticsearchTemplate(
                jestClient,
                elasticsearchConverter,
                new DefaultJestResultsMapper(simpleElasticsearchMappingContext, mapper));
        }

        public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

            private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

            public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
                this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
                objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
                objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
                objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, true);
                objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, false);
                objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, true);
            }

            @Override
            public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            }

            @Override
            public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
                return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
            }
        }
    @Bean
    public JestClient createJestClient(){
    JestHttpClient build() {
      JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
      Builder builder =
          new HttpClientConfig.Builder(cfg.urls)
              .multiThreaded(true)
              .discoveryEnabled(false)
              .connTimeout((int) cfg.connectionTimeout)
              .maxConnectionIdleTime(cfg.maxConnectionIdleTime, cfg.maxConnectionIdleUnit)
              .maxTotalConnection(cfg.maxTotalConnection)
              .readTimeout(cfg.readTimeout)
              .requestCompressionEnabled(cfg.requestCompression)
              .discoveryFrequency(1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

      if (cfg.username != null && cfg.password != null) {
        builder.defaultCredentials(cfg.username, cfg.password);
      }

      factory.setHttpClientConfig(builder.build());
      return (JestHttpClient) factory.getObject();
    }
    }


    }
```

Try to add this configuration bean, so that it uses the JestClient with your credentials. you have to put your own values for where my cfg.whatever is

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm really new to ES so I didn't understand your answer, I didn't create any config classes.
just create configs in properties file like in the description, in java I created repository, entity and service classes.

Comment: @AhmedE.Eldeeb Updated. Im not in a place where i can be certain that compiles but you can get an idea.

Comment: thanks again, this answer helps me a lot, I think this code is from a Jhipster project and you missed the properties in .yml file, anyway thnx man

Comment: It is. i just added the jestClient configuration part. Which is what i think u need